# Wordpress WooCommerce - Использовать дочернюю тему только для магазина

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

В данный момент на сайте используется хук, добавляющий в основную тему функционал WooCommerce.

На своем сайте они призывают к использованию дочерней темы, однако все лишь ведет к тому, что родительская тема остается нетронутой, а дочерняя применяется для всего сайта.

Было бы замечательно иметь родительскую тему для всего сайта + дочернюю только для страниц WooCommerce. Есть ли способ это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Такого способа нет. Дочерняя тема всегда работает для всего сайта.

Использование дочерних тем - правильный подход, позволяющий вносить изменения в темы и некоторые продвинутые плагины (например, WooCommerce) и при этом не зависеть от обновлений родительских тем и плагинов.

В то же время обновления тем и плагинов зачастую являются критически важными, закрывая дыры в безопасности.

Comment: Непонятно, почему использование дочерней темы вызывает вопросы. Простейшая дочерняя тема состоит всего из одного файла style.css и не создает никакой дополнительной нагрузки на сайт.

Comment: Я не против дочерних тем. Просто текущий хук добавляет css и js файлы WooCommerce во все страницы сайта. И этого хотелось бы избежать

Comment: Влияние этих дополнительных css и js на скорость отклика ничтожно. Но если очень хочется оптимизировать сайт, то самое простое решение - плагин Plugin Organizer https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/
С его помощью можно включать плагины только на тех страницах, где они нужны.